# Confirmation of coolant valve on a Ford Focus

Tags: ford, coolant, maintenance, focus

I'm prepping a radiator coolant change on a 2014 Ford Focus, and would like to confirm if the valve with a 1/2" diameter pipe shown in the picture is the one that needs to be turned to release the coolant.

Is the correct one identified?

[image]

To possibly help answer the question, an additional picture from a different angle is shown below.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what that appears to be. You can see it here in this image of the radiator. Bottom left.

[image]

Comment: ♦ Thanks, RockAuto.com seems to be a very good source; I'll try to look up that website first prior to any other inquiries.